# Story about atoms being entire universes/solar systems and their inhabitants invade the world

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space

About 5 years ago I read a story about scientists discovering that atoms are tiny universes/solar systems. Then at some point the scientists develope a microscope that can see the planets and their inhabitants. Later on the scientists realize that the atom people already have technology far beyond ours (because they can travel from atom to atom and colonize the planets)

Comment: Novel or short story? Read online or in a magazine or a collection? Did it seem like a very old story? How did the atom people "invade" our world? Did they make themselves bigger?

Comment: sorry I didn't really clarify it enough; the atom people just flew from atom to atom conquering the other tiny worlds and eventually they lived on every atom on Earth, then they "invaded" some how which is one of the parts i can't remember. I think it might have been a short story, but I do remember I had it on a PDF file in my old computer which was destoryed in a flood.

Comment: that's remind me this [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/342/87517) of a question about largest object ever dreamed in SF

Comment: John Russell Fearn wrote several stories like this.

Comment: It sounds a bit like like ["He Who Shrank"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He_Who_Shrank) and ["Out of the Sub-Universe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Frederick_Starzl#Short_stories), but several aspects differ.

Comment: plot remotely looks similar to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64711/microcosm-that-lives-on-a-mans-knuckle

Answer (score -1):

I know it isn't, but it sure sounds very similar to "The Micronauts" a late 70's early 80's Marvel comic book. Good story, and J.J. Abrams was going to make what probably would have been a terrible movie adaptation of it, but he got busy with star wars and dropped it (thank god)
The comic has been remade several times, usually nowhere near as good as the first run was.
Good luck.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It may not be the right medium, but it might be an adaption.  Can you provide more details of the story, and less editorializing?

Comment: I can just shoot you a wiki link if you feel like reading more about it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micronauts_(comics)